# Incompatible types error for union assignment

Tags: c, rpc

I am trying to assign a XDR union into a structure union once the former has been populated by the svc_getargs() RPC call. However, I am getting an "Types are incompatible" error while I am doing so. I also tried memcpy() but same problem there as well. Below is my code. Appreciate the help.

```
struct data_str {
    struct svc_req *rqstp;
    SVCXPRT *transp;
    bool_t retval;
    xdrproc_t _xdr_result;
    //outputImage get_minified_image_1_res;
    //inputImage get_minified_image_1_arg;
    union {
        inputImage get_minified_image_1_arg;
    } argument;
    bool_t (*local)(char *, void *, struct svc_req *);
};

static void
minify_image_program_1(struct svc_req *rqstp, register SVCXPRT *transp) {

    struct data_str *req_holder;
    union {
        inputImage get_minified_image_1_arg;
    } argument;
    union {
        outputImage get_minified_image_1_res;
    } result;
    xdrproc_t _xdr_argument, _xdr_result;
    bool_t (*local)(char *, void *, struct svc_req *);

    req_holder = malloc(sizeof(*req_holder));
    req_holder->rqstp = rqstp;
    req_holder->transp = transp;

    memset((char *) &argument, 0, sizeof(argument));
    if (!svc_getargs (transp, (xdrproc_t) _xdr_argument, (caddr_t) &argument)) {
        svcerr_decode(transp);
        return;
    }
    req_holder->_xdr_result = _xdr_result;
    req_holder->argument = argument; // THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
    req_holder->local = local;
    return;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Some more context. This for a project that has two parts around Remote Procedure Calls (RPC) - first a single threaded server and second a multi threaded one. The code above is for the 2nd part where I am trying to modify RPC's auto-generated "svc" to make it multithreaded (MT) with a boss-worker pattern. The auto-generated files work perfectly for the single-threaded part. But for the MT part, I need to take the "argument" variable from the Boss thread and provide it to the worker threads; worker threads then get the required data (a minified image) from the server and return to the client.

Comment: Why do you have unions with only one member?

Comment: Your union is unnamed.

Comment: That union is generated by rpcgen. I don't have control over it.

Comment: the posted code does not compile for several reasons including missing the `stdlib.h` and `string.h` header files. the union is missing a 'tag' name,  no prototype for: `svc_getargs()` and `svcerr_decode()`

Comment: `input_image` and `output_image` are not defined in the posted code.  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: the modifier `register`, in modern C, only has the effect of making the parameter 'read only'

Comment: the type `SVCXPRT` is not defined anywhere in the posted code

Comment: If the union is untagged in the structure definition, the author of the structure (the indirect original author, if the final code is automatically generated) did not intend for you to use it directly. You could `memcpy` into it, and you could assign to the member inside it (as with `req_holder->argument.get_minified_image_1_arg = argument.get_minified_image_1_arg`. However, you should be concerned that this is not what the author intended you to do.

Comment: the `struct svc_req` is not defined anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: @user3629249: Those comments are not very helpful. We already know what the issue is, and we do not need an MVCE to diagnose or discuss it. The things those comments point out are not actual problems in the full code, as it undoubtedly defines the various items and includes the necessary headers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, thanks for your answer below and the comments above. I have already tried what you mentioned in your first comment above, it gave me different problems. Let me try to provide some more context behind the problem. The project I am working on had two parts around RPC - first a single threaded server and second a multi threaded one. The code above is for the 2nd part where I am trying to modify RPC's auto-generated "svc" to make it multithreaded with a boss-worker pattern. I need to take the "argument" variable and somehow provide it to the worker threads. Hence the quandary.

Answer (score 1):

Two unions (or structures) without tags are considered to be different types even if they have identical declarations. Different unions (or structures) are incompatible (within the translation unit).

To use the same union in multiple places, first declare it with a tag:

```
union MyTag { contents of union… };
```

then refer to it using its tag name, as in `union MyTag argument;`.